# What is the Pythonic way to pull conditional cell value from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

My data frame, `new_df`, includes 3 columns: "name", "gender", and "Total".  I need to pull the value from the total column per a combination of name and gender.

```
        name        gender  Total
357328  Barbara     F       3114462
357329  Patricia    F       3846693
357330  Betty       F       1138056
357331  Shirley     F       1075104
357332  Carol       F       2054088
```

```py
my_name = 'Betty'
new_df[(new_df.name == my_name) & (new_df.gender == 'F')]['Total'])
```

This code works returns the correct value, `1138056`, but I am sure there is a better way to get the result.

Comment: Your approach is good enough, if your selected combination is in the dataframe once. For a good approach recommendation, you need to define what you want if it's in more than once or not at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for filter by mask and also by column name, output is `Series`:

```
my_name = 'Betty'
s = new_df.loc[(new_df.name == my_name) & (new_df.gender == 'F'), 'Total']

print (s)
357330    1138056
Name: Total, dtype: int64
```

And then if matched at least one value and need select first:

```
print (s.values[0])
1138056
print (s.iloc[0])
1138056
print (s.iat[0])
1138056
```

Or if possible no match value is possible use `next` with `iter`, where is possible set default value:

```
print (next(iter(s), 'no match'))
1138056
```

---

```
my_name = 'John'
s = new_df.loc[(new_df.name == my_name) & (new_df.gender == 'F'), 'Total']

print (next(iter(s), 'no match'))
no match
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I prefer using `loc` with lambda function as it does not require creating the dataframe in the first place and can be used as part of a method chain.

```
new_df.loc[lambda x: (x.name == my_name) & (x.gender == 'F'), 'Total']
```